# Details of automatic cell-grouping w.r.t. cell-style

Tags: notebooks

What determines how a specific cell-style influences grouping of cells?

For example `"Text"` following `"Subtitle"` is grouped but not following `"Text"`

```
nbtitle = CreateDocument[];
NotebookWrite[nbtitle, Cell["subtitle", "Subtitle"]]
NotebookWrite[nbtitle, Cell["this text gets grouped", "Text"]]

nbtext = CreateDocument[];
NotebookWrite[nbtext, Cell["some text", "Text"]];
NotebookWrite[nbtext, Cell["this text is not grouped", "Text"]];
```

[image: title]

---

[image: text]

All I can find [in the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/CellsAsMathematicaExpressions.html) is:

> Within a given notebook, there is always a collection of styles that can be used to determine the appearance and behavior of cells. Typically the styles are named so as to reflect what role cells which have them will play in the notebook.

Comment: Each style has parameter [`CellGroupingRules`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CellGroupingRules.html) or inherit it. If it is what you are looking for then I post it as answer (with some examples).

Comment: @ybeltukov Too slow :) Thanks, it was

Comment: Not I but my Internet. I didn't see the update :)

Comment: Please check [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/79099/random-polyhedra-walk) out when you have time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The option that governs this behaviour is `CellGroupingRules`

[image]

By changing the grouping I can make sections group under text e.g.

[image]

due to

[image]

Notice that a number accompanies the grouping assignment. This allows you to allocate an order to the grouping -- lower numbers have higher rank.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I can cancel the ritual sacrifice for the cell gods now